# I want to retrieve data between two dates of two differrent years from MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

```
select * from rechargetable 
where Format (CurTime, 'Short Date') between  #12/31/2014#  
and  #01/02/2015#  and Channel = 'Channel15' 
order by autono desc
```

And

```
select * from rechargetable 
where Format (CurTime, 'Short Date')>=#12/31/2014#  
and Format (CurTime, 'Short Date')<=#01/02/2015#  and Channel = 'Channel15' 
order by autono desc
```

It shows all records from database, it works fine if it is searched between 12/30/2014 to 12/31/2014

Comment: Start by taking out those nonsensical calls to Format (every one of them! you don't compare a formatted date string with a date literal! come on!) and we'll talk.

Comment: Is [CurTime] a `Date/Time` field in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Format changes any value to a string, so you are comparing two strings. Consider DateValue

```
SELECT * FROM rechargetable 
WHERE DateValue(CurTime) Between #2014/12/31# And #2015/01/02# 
AND Channel = 'Channel15' 
ORDER BY autono Desc
```